# Nodejs crashes when reading from disk

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, fs, pm2

I'm working on a website based on expressjs which streams videos and users can download video files from it.
when I start the app, everything works well. But after some while app can not stream videos and downloading files doesn't work too(it returns an empty file after a long delay) the only way to fix it is to restart the app.

nginx error log:

```
2017/01/16 19:39:39 [error] 10584#10584: *23717 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: example.com, request: "GET /api/course/.../video/.../stream HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/course/.../video/.../stream", host: "example.com"
```

I use pm2 in cluster mode .

I have this in the app for logging errors:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  winston.error('Caught exception : ' ,err);
});
```

But there is no error in log files.

for streaming video I use an approach similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976123/streaming-a-video-file-to-an-html5-video-player-with-node-js-so-that-the-video-c) .
for downloading files I use express download function.

Comment: Could you be leaking file handles or some other system resource and eventually you run out?

Answer (score -1):

First, check winston daily rotate file, they have a transport for logging unhandled exceptions. Second, if after sometime your app becomes slow, it is possible that you have a memory leak because the garbage collection slows the process or the thread gets blocked by a long running synchronus code, it will be helpful if you show your code here.