# How to produce a continuous stream of videos?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to stream two or three videos one after the other (extracting the names from an array and then loading them from file system would be enough) and without any sign that the prevous one has finished before showing the one that follows.
I found some examples for single video streaming but I didn't manage to adapt them.

https://medium.com/@daspinola/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6

[Streaming a video file to an html5 video player with Node.js so that the video controls continue to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976123/streaming-a-video-file-to-an-html5-video-player-with-node-js-so-that-the-video-c/24977085#24977085)

Where can I find something more suitable or how can I modify those examples?

Comment: Hello, have any code you've tried so far ? maybe the important snippets from the links u posted?

Comment: Those examples you found have rather little to do with what you want. (“Streaming” in those contexts refers to the way the video data is send from the client to the server.) If you want to play videos one after the other, then you have to go look into the methods and events offered by the `video` element - to find out the play time of an already loaded video, and/or react to when it is finished.

Comment: @Andrew perhaps mine wasn't a good starting, I'm not improving that way for now

Comment: @misorude it sounds interesting but can't find more hints (I tried googling *"require video" node js site:stackoverflow.com* or just *"require video" node js+). Could you suggest better ideas?

Comment: I was talking about the basic HTML5 `video` element, resp. the JS methods and events it exposes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement

Comment: @misorude does it concerne node js?

Comment: No, talking about client-side JavaScript here.

Comment: Unless you want to combine all videos you have into one single video server-side first, that would probably involve something like FFmpeg then.