# Is there a way to play video by reading it in packet?

Tags: html, video

Is there a way to play the entire video by reading it in packet from the front instead of loading it in full?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for a way to stream a video, where you don't need to wait for the complete video to be downloaded and then played..

A simple Video tag should allow you to do so:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Video</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video src="some_video.mp4" width="1280px" height="720px" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Also a similar issue solved can be found here: [Streaming a video file to an html5 video player with Node.js so that the video controls continue to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976123/streaming-a-video-file-to-an-html5-video-player-with-node-js-so-that-the-video-c)

and also a good introduction on how video streaming works on the web here: https://medium.com/canal-tech/how-video-streaming-works-on-the-web-an-introduction-7919739f7e1

Comment: I got 2 thread. One is writing video file, and the other is playing it in html.
But, It doesn't work on web browser using this method.
I think the video writing was something wrong or video tag in html can't open being written video file

Comment: It will be good if you share the code that you are using, it will give more context

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/github/BeomJinJeong/KPUproj/blob/master/cuda10_0_tensorflow_gpu1_13_1.ipynb

Comment: I'm programming video streaming with RCNN. Capturing youtube video and detecting frames is successful. now, displaying the frames to html is the left now. 

please installing tensorflow 1.13.1, and cuda, pafy, youtube dll, flask-ngrok and run the last cell.